# Yii bootstrap, adding id and class to TbBootstrap

Tags: php, class, twitter-bootstrap, yii

i'm using PHP Yii framework, and came across a problem regarding adding Id and other attributes to a tab. I'm using yii bootstrap by the way as extension:

```
$tabs = array(
        'item1' => array(
            'label' => 'label1',
            'content' => $content1,
        ),
        'preview' => array(
            'label' => 'Preview',
        ),
    );

$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbWizard', 
     array(
        'id' => 'harvest-tabs',
        'type' => 'tabs',
        'tabs' => $tabs,
        'pagerContent' => false,
    ));
```

How do i add an 'id' and 'class' property to each of the tab 'item1' and 'preview'?
i tried:

```
'item1' => array(
                'label' => 'label1',
                'content' => $content1,
                'id' => 'some id'
                'class' => 'some class'
            ),
            'preview' => array(
                'label' => 'Preview',
                'id' => 'some other id'
                'class' => 'some other class'
            ),
```

But this doesn't add a class to it. I only see `<li>'s`
that serves as the container for the tabs. Sorry i'm a newbie here. I'd appreciate any help Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
'item1' => array(
    'label' => 'label1',
    'content' => $content1,
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'id' => 'some id'
        'class' => 'some class'
    ),
),
```

I haven't tried it but I'm following yii bootstrap logic here. Tell me if it's not working.